# Using LAG/LEAD to find peaks in data gives decade changes (ie 9, 99, 999) as well as correct peaks

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data in the dbase is collected once every minute.  Weld_Minutes will increment up until reset at the end of shift or product change.  The code finds the peak Weld_Minutes.  Unfortunately it see the transition from 9 to 10 minutes as a peak as well as 99 minutes to 100.  I'm at a loss as to why.  Also I am a noob.

```
        select
                case when pt = 1 then DateInserted end as Day_and_Time,
        case when pt = 1 then Weld_Time end as Weld_Minutes,
        case when pt = 1 then Ft_Ran end as Feet_Ran
from (
      select *, case
                 when DateInserted BETWEEN '2019-05-19 06:00:00' AND '2019-05-21 06:10:00'
              and lag(Weld_Time) over(order by DateInserted) <= Weld_Time 
                  and lead(Weld_Time) over(order by DateInserted) < Weld_Time then 1 -- peak
            end as pt
      from mill_30
     ) sq
where pt is not null;
```

The results from the query:

```
+-------------------------+--------------+----------+
|      Day_and_Time       | Weld_Minutes | Feet_Ran |
+-------------------------+--------------+----------+
| 2019-05-20 09:40:54.157 |            9 |      208 |
| 2019-05-20 16:51:00.130 |           34 |      595 |
| 2019-05-20 17:48:01.207 |            9 |      148 |
| 2019-05-20 20:48:01.567 |           99 |     1628 |
| 2019-05-21 01:06:04.083 |          308 |     5933 |
| 2019-05-21 01:15:04.263 |            9 |      185 |
| 2019-05-21 01:41:04.217 |           34 |      721 |
+-------------------------+--------------+----------+
The Weld_Minutes 9, 9, 99, and 9 are not peaks.  34, 308, and 34 are the correct peaks.
```

Comment: If you could provide your sample data that would be great, instead of query results.

Comment: What's the data type for `weld_time`? Also, raw data would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, can't say for sure without datatypes, but from your description it sounds like it's sorting alphabetically, not numerically (which it would do if Weld_Minutes is a varchar, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to follow.  There is no `weld_time` column in your sample data.  And no `weld_minutes` in the question.  These might be related.

You would see this problem if the column you are comparing is a *string*, not a number.  I would suggest that you cast it to a number (integer, numeric, float) for your comparisons.

Because the data and the question are out-of-synch, I'm describing the solution rather than writing out the code.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the help.  The numbers are saved a varchar which seems to be the issue.  You are correct in that weld_time is renamed to weld_minutes for readability for the end user.